# What does it mean when it is said that an Intel CPU is assembled in Country X?

Tags: cpu, manufacturing-process

I was reading a same question posted on Quora but wanted to ask the same question here on this forum. So if the CPU states that it is assembled in some country X what does that mean exactly ? What assembly (**not referring to the manufacturing process**) in detail is done in country X ? I'm a noob when it comes to Electrical Engineering so please try to explain in layman's terms if at possible. Thanks

Comment: You mean like wire bonding the die to the package pins and encapsulating everything into the package? That's separate from the production of the silicon die itself.

Comment: DKNguyen@ Yes exactly and well put.

Comment: Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bor0qLifjz4) as it will answer some questions. Pay special attention to the packaging part at the end. At this stage the wafers are in a state where these can be safely transported to other locations and packaged. We are talking about hundreds of millions of wafers so there is a financial advantage in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Usually "assembled" means that some action was performed that changed the state of product, for example by combining different components, perhaps from different suppliers.

However there was not necessarily enough **value added** for it to be considered "made in" that country or region. Different countries have different regulations on what content is required for country of origin markings (if any) to say what. It gets very complex.

There is no way (from the markings) to determine what exactly was done in country 'X', but almost surely it was not particularly high tech in comparison to making the die itself.

It has not been uncommon in the past to ship dies made in country 'A' to a lower wage country 'B' where more labor intensive packaging operations were performed, and then the packaged chip might be shipped to a third country 'C' where the product was actually assembled into a finished product, that is then shipped to various other countries (perhaps including country 'A' among others) around the globe. So a wafer from Japan might be made into dies in California, shipped to the Philippines for packaging, and then to China for assembly, and then through Rotterdam to Europe for consumers to enjoy. Of course automation technology and various other factors affect supply chains over time so the names and countries tend to slowly change over time.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany@ thank you. Aside from the fabrication process where the CAD blueprints (layout/schematics/plots) would be needed no doubt yes ? Then would the assembly process require the use of these same design blueprints (possibly called layout/schematics/plots) in order to assemble the final product ? Also those surface mounted capacitors shown on the CPU die (on most modern day Intel CPU's) do they get mounted by the assembly process yes ?

Comment: There would only be very limited information passed for the assembly process. Probably the caps would be mounted as part of the process but it’s always possible some steps take place in other facilities or other countries entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The process to produce the actual integrated circuit on silicon is separate from the process to place it in the packaging that houses it.

So the fab where the silicon is produced could be in one country, but it could be assembled in to its package (plastic and pins) in another.

If you want to know more you can look up information/videos showing how integrated circuits are produced (e.g. semiconductor lithography), vs how the resulting bit of silicon gets placed inside and connected to the packaging (e.g. wire bonding).

Answer (score 0):

None of the CPU's are manufactured in China. Only smaller chipsets are built in China.

Intel does most of the CPU wafer fabs in Ireland but does final assy and test elsewhere.

They employ 33k in manufacturing which is in several partitions, including;

1. **Foundry**: [Wafer production](https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2021/03/intel-foundry-services-fact-sheet-229940.pdf)
2. **Chip:**  Assembly & Test
3. **Motherboard**: Assembly & Test
4. **Server System** : IFS Assembly & Test  (IBM> , Amazon, Google etc)

https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/architecture-and-technology/global-manufacturing.html?wapkw=%20manufacturing

With the 2022 Investor presentation, you can learn the history and future plans of trillion dollar new manufacturing to **redistribute factory locations** to prevent supply chain risks and accelerate technology to stay on Moore's Law log curve for transistors per chip.

**Essentially to increase factories in USA, Malaysia and EU.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KByyChZj064

Comment: TonyStewart@ Thank you. What do you mean chipset ? Does the Memory Controller and IO Interface IC section of the CPU die get manufactured in China for example ?

Comment: yes .. that is possible https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONkv4dM6SVM

Comment: dependence on TSMC for future products is declining. Intel is purchasing foundry DNA from $5B Force